# Find users who have not uploaded certain contents in last 30 days

Tags: 6, users, database

I need to find users who have not uploaded certain contents in last 30 days. I have tried this query it is not working. Can anyone help me?

> select uid, max(created) as max_created from node where 
>   node.type in ('page','story') AND
>   max_created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000

I am getting error in phpmyadmin:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'max_created' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 3):

SQL is **evaluated backwards**, from right to left. So the `WHERE` clause is parsed and evaluate prior to the `SELECT` clause. Because of this the aliasing of `MAX(created)` to `max_created` not yet occurred.

You can try this,

> SELECT uid, MAX(created) FROM node WHERE node.type IN ('page','story')
>   HAVING MAX(created) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000

Comment: Not sure why you'd need to re-query the same table, just `AND MAX(created) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000` would be perfectly sufficient. +1 for the explanation though

Comment: I get this error with I do that `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Oops yeah you're right, not sure where my head was at. Correct query would be `SELECT uid, MAX(created) FROM node WHERE node.type IN ('page','story') HAVING MAX(created) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000`

Comment: @ARUN You'll probably want to `GROUP BY uid` in that case

Comment: @Clive So Both Having and Group by are needed?

Comment: If you have a read through the docs for `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` you should be able to answer that yourself very easily. Mercifully they're pretty straightforward concepts

Comment: I tried this, `SELECT uid, MAX(created) FROM node WHERE node.type IN ('page','story') group by uid HAVING MAX(created) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000` this also returning only one result.

Comment: check it again, may be you have only one record matching your query :)

Comment: @shrish I checked. there is more than one result in db. But query not fetching.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this. Why not just `select uid, max(created) as max_created from node where node.type in ('page','story') AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000`?

Comment: @ARUN Try this, `select uid,created from node where node.type in ('page','story') AND created < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-2592000`